# How to make a error message display:none and display:block?

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, state

I have a method that does not define ShowErrorWarning in the render area. I need to use state. But how can I get this function valid?

I already tried to use the error-message as a function ShowErrorMessage above the class. But then I can not include state.

```
function ShowWarning() {

let error = this.props.warningError.error;   

    if (error === "") {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            errorStyle: {
                display: 'none'
            },
            warningMessage: ''
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            errorStyle: {
                display: 'block'
            },
            warningMessage: this.props.warningError.message
        }); 
    }

}
```

The error message will show as a separate component when i get an error from the API call. This is stored in this.props.warningError.error.

Comment: And I forgot to mention <ShowErrorWarning style={ this.state.errorStyle }>
                    { this.state.warningMessage }
                </ShowErrorWarning> in the render area.

Comment: It's not the issue, but you don't need to mention`...this.state` in `this.setState`

Comment: How are you calling `ShowWarning` ?

Comment: It is actually showErrorWarning, just a spelling mistake. But I still hvae the same problem. Maybe I must work out some JSX magic.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a simple ternary operator in your JSX and either render the required component or `null` based on `warningError.error` containing a message.

```
render() {
  const { warningError } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>
      {warningError.error !== '' ? <ErrorComponent message={warningError.message} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are on to something. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I get Request failed with status code 404, which is correct. Now I must see if It turns off when I do not have a request fail.